# Python 3 - How to terminate a thread instantly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

In my code (a complex GUI application with Tkinter) I have a thread defined in a custom object (a progress bar). It runs a function with a while cicle like this:

```
def Start(self):
    while self.is_active==True:
        do it..
        time.sleep(1)
        do it..
        time.sleep(1)
    
def Stop(self):
    self.is_active=False
```

It can terminate only when another piece of code, placed in another thread, changes the attribute **self.is_active** using the method **self.Stop()**. I have the same situation in another custom object (a counter) and both of them have to work together when the another thread (the main one) works.

The code works, but I realized that the two threads associated with the progress bar and the counter don't terminate instantly as I wanted, because before to temrinate, they need to wait the end of their functions, and these ones are slow becose of the **time.sleep(1)** instructions. From the user point of view, it means see the end of the main thread with the progress bar and the cunter that terminate LATE and I don't like it.

To be honest I don't know how to solve this issue. Is there a way to force a thread to terminate instantly without waiting the end of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, to be clear, [hard-killing a thread is a terrible idea in any language, and Python doesn't support it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/323972/364696); if nothing else, the risk of that thread holding a lock which is never unlocked, causing any thread that tries to acquire it to deadlock, is a fatal flaw.

If you don't care about the thread at all, you can create it with the `daemon=True` argument, and it will die if all non-daemon threads in the process have exited. But if the thread really should die with proper cleanup (e.g. it might have `with` statements or the like that manage cleanup of resources outside the process, that won't be cleaned up on process termination), that's not a real solution.

That said, you can avoid waiting a second or more by switching from using a plain `bool` and `time.sleep` to using an `Event` and using the `.wait` method on it. This will allow the "sleeps" to be interrupted immediately, at the small expense of requiring you to reverse your condition (because `Event.wait` only blocks while it's false/unset, so you need the flag to be based on when you should stop, not when you are currently active):

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self):
        self.should_stop = threading.Event()  # Create an unset event on init
    
    def Start(self):
        while not self.should_stop.is_set():
            # do it..

            if self.should_stop.wait(1):
                break

            # do it..

            if self.should_stop.wait(1):
                break

    def Stop(self):
        self.should_stop.set()
```

On modern Python (3.1 and higher) the `wait` method returns `True` if the event was set (on beginning the wait or because it got set while waiting), and `False` otherwise, so whenever `wait` returns `True`, that means you were told to stop and you can immediately `break` out of the loop. You also get notified almost immediately, instead of waiting up to one second before you can check the flag.

This won't cause the real "do it.." code to exit immediately, but from what you said, it sounds like that part of the code isn't all that long, so waiting for it to complete isn't a big hassle.

If you really want to preserve the `is_active` attribute for testing whether it's still active, you can define it as a property that reverses the meaning of the `Event`, e.g.:

```
 @property
 def is_active(self):
     return not self.should_stop.is_set()
```

Answer (score 0):

the safest way to do it without risking a segmentation fault, is to return.

```py
def Start(self):
    while self.is_active==True:
        do it..
        if not self.is_active: return
        time.sleep(1)
        if not self.is_active: return
        do it..
        if not self.is_active: return
        time.sleep(1)
    
def Stop(self):
    self.is_active=False
```

python threads need to free the associated resources, and while "killing" the thread is possible using some C tricks, you will be risking a segmentation fault or a memory leak.

here is a cleaner way to do it.

```py
class MyError(Exception):
    pass
def Start(self):
    try:
        while self.is_active==True:
            do it..
            self.check_termination()
            time.sleep(1)
            self.check_termination()
            do it..
            self.check_termination()
            time.sleep(1)
    except MyError:
        return

def check_termination(self):
    if not self.is_active:
        raise MyError
```

and you can call `self.check_termination()` from inside any function to terminate this loop, not necessarily from inside `Start` directly.

Edit: ShadowRanger solution handles the "interruptable wait" better, i am just keeping this for implementing a kill switch for the thread that can be checked from anywhere inside the thread.

Comment: How is the second bit of code any cleaner? Seems like replacing `return` with `break` in your original code gets all the same benefits (ability to run additional code after the loop is terminated before returning), and I'm not seeing any real benefit to defining a custom exception for breaking out of a single layer loop when plain `break` achieves the same results with less boilerplate.

Comment: @ShadowRanger just to compress code to 1 line instead of 2 which it improves code visibility, i like your answer more, but i think it could be shrunk using such helper function, especially when this function is calling more functions inside and you need to propagate the loop stop.

Comment: Eh. I'm actually okay with it not being shrunk in this case; I don't *want* to hide the fact that the code might break out of the loop there. It's also not really more visible; you've hidden what actually happens in a separate function; the name of the function gives a hint to what it's doing, but two lines are going to be a little more visible than a one-liner buried in the rest of the code.