How to close an asynchronous task that hosts a simple synchronous HTTPServer?
I have the following Python code snippet:
import asyncio
import http.server
import socketserver


class StoppableHTTPServer(socketserver.TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

    def stop(self):
        self.shutdown()
        
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

def blocking_function(server):
    print("This is a blocking function.")
    with server:
        print("Serving on port 80")
        server.serve_forever()

async def main():
    server = StoppableHTTPServer(("", 80), Handler)
    task = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.to_thread(blocking_function, server))
    
    # Allow the server to run for 3 seconds
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    
    # Cancel the task
    task.cancel()
    
    try:
        await task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Task was cancelled.")
        server.stop()  # Stop the server upon cancellation
    
    print("Back to event loop.")
    
asyncio.run(main())

This script aims to run a synchronous blocking_function in a separate thread to prevent it from blocking the main event loop. The goal is to shut down the server after three seconds, which is working properly but only when there are no active connections to the webserver, when an active connection exists (e.g., using netcat 0.0.0.0 80), the script does not exit after three seconds and instead remains stuck on the HTTPServer task.
How can I mitigate this and make it also exit properly even if there are active connections?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74521233/python-3-how-to-terminate-a-thread-instantly.  Python does not support the killing of a running thread, and with good reason.  The best you can do is wait for the thread to finish its work, which is what you are doing.

When I posted this comment I had not realized that you asked a very similar question a few hours ago, and it has already been closed as a duplicate.  Please don't do that here.  They closed your first question for a reason: Python doesn't allow one thread to abruptly cancel another, period, end of story.  You may not like it, and you may not understand the reasoning behind it.  But it's the truth and you really should stop wanting to do it.

This question is similar to: Python 3 - How to terminate a thread instantly?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
